# React protected route with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I created a separate `node.js` `restful API` for checking if the user token is valid. I did this for my react protected routes, even though most of my `endpoints` already checks the user token.

My redux Thunk:

```
const verifyToken = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:9999/authenticate", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` },
      })
      .then(async (resp) => {
        const { message } = await resp.data;
        console.log(message);
        if (message === "verified") dispatch({ type: "signIn-success" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({ type: "logout-user" });
      });
  };
};
```

Protected Route:

```
const ProtectedRoute: FC<{ children: ReactNode; path: string }> = ({
  children,
  path,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  dispatch(verifyToken()); //dispatch thunk
  const status = useSelector((store: RootStore) => store.status)

  return status && status === "loggedOut" ? (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  ) : (
    <Route path={path} render={() => <>{children}</>} />
  );
};
```

The problem is that it takes time to `dispatch` my thunk, so it redirects to `"/"` even though the user token checking hasn't finished.

So what happens is, the value of status is `"loggedOut"` at first then my thunk will check if the token is valid. If it is, status becomes `"loggedIn"`, but its too late because it already redirected to `"/"`

Comment: You should add a "pending" or "processing" state and conditionally ***not*** render the route or redirect until the updated status is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loading for the time you're dispatching the action, something like this:

```
const ProtectedRoute: FC<{ children: ReactNode, path: string }> = ({
  children,
  path,
}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const status = useSelector((store: RootStore) => store.status);

  async function verify() {
    await dispatch(verifyToken()); //dispatch thunk
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    verify();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Show Loading...</div>;

return status === "loggedOut" ? (
  <Redirect to="/" />
) : (
  <Route path={path} render={() => <>{children}</>} />
);
};
```

Comment: It worked but I also needed to add "await" on my thunk. "await axios()"